# How do I create a Git branch that merges with both the master branch and production branch

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, version-control, merge

I'm very new to Git VCS and have created a git repository for my web application in Visual Studio. I have a master branch from which I would like to create a production branch with minor configuration changes that will ultimately be pushed to my remote server. Now how would I go about, or what would be the best way to create a branch that will allow me to add features to my website, on both the master and production branch, maintaining the different configurations between my master branch and production branch.

For example, if I have two files and file A in master differs slightly from file A in production but would like to create a branch that manipulates File B and applies the changes on both my master and production branch, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the new branch from any of `master` or `production` branch.

Then you can develop on the new branch, and merge the branch into `master` and `production` branch separately. It's ok for you to merge new created branch twice into separate branches.

Comment: Ahh, that's what I needed clarity on. For that reason, I'll mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I got your scenario in a correct way. So you have a master branch wich contains general code base, etc. and a production branch which however should be same like the master just with correct edited configuration files for the productive system, right?

You in general could just create the productive branch out of your master once. If you work in your repo you would merge into the master and each time you want to update your productive your would merge master into productive.

Comment: When you say "repo" are you referring to a new branch which I would merge with both my production and master as Marina pointed out? Or is this another approach?

Comment: Yes. I ment any working branch inside the repository. Like in general, when using the gitflow you have a master branch, a develop branch and bugfix / feature branches, maybe support branches for old versions. When working you always create a new branch for each feature bug based on the develop branch (or support branch if this a fix for an older version) and merge it back into its origin later. In general it is said develop always should compile and master should only contain changes which might be released at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax to create a new branch from existing branch

```
git checkout -b <branch_name>
```

So first go to your master branch -

```
git checkout master
```

Then create new branch from there and later push your branch by pushing in the changes

```
git checkout -b production
git push -u origin production
```

Comment: Thanks Sagar, this will come in handy.